# Understanding & updating npm on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I've been trying (in vain) to update `global npm`.

**Current:**

```
$ npm --version
2.15.5
$ sudo npm install npm -g
/usr/local/bin/bin/npm -> /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@4.0.5 /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/npm
$ npm --version
2.15.5
```

**Env:**

```
$ sudo cat ~/.bashrc
NPM_PACKAGES="/home/user/.npm-packages"
NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 May 25  2016 /usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody jadeye 4096 Dec 27 20:31 node-gyp-bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody jadeye  833 Sep 10 02:43 npm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody jadeye 2131 Dec  2 03:14 npm-cli.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody jadeye  483 Sep 10 02:43 npm.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody jadeye  513 Oct 25 04:09 read-package-json.js
```

I've read around about this...obviously mostly here on SO...
Couldn't figure this out (for months now) and could get npm to upgrade.
Please explain:

1. Where is the global npm installed?? `/usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/`??
2. Where is `npm -v` reading from? (same place??)
3. How do I go about updating global `npm version`?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I searched for hours on end....in vain.
Until this:

[npm-removal - Cleaning the Slate](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm)

```
$ sudo npm uninstall npm -g
```

**Didn't work so I went for something more extreme..**

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
```

**& still nothing...it wouldn't move...**

```
$ sudo npm -v
    2.15.1
$ which npm
    /usr/bin/npm
```

**So what if I do this:**

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/npm 
$ sudo npm -v
    sudo: npm: command not found
```

**Finally some results:**

```
$ which npm
    /usr/local/bin/bin/npm
$ npm -v
    4.0.5
```

Hope this helps someone....